# Send String into activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to send a String into an Activity:

```
public class MyHttpClientUsage {

  public MyHttpClientUsage(){}

  public void getInfoAbout() throws HttpException{

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("a", "Static");
    params.put("content", "47");

    MyHttpClient.get("", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
        //How can I send this response
      }

    });
  }
}
```

I can't use intent because `get()` method is static so I can't instance the Context or something else in `MyHttpClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bundle basket2 = new Bundle();
    basket2.putInt("ID", 3);
            Intent yourIntent = new Intent("YourActivity");
            yourIntent.putExtras(basket2);
            startActivity(YourIntent);
```

Comment: Are you sure that he wants to send the string from an activity?

Comment: I'm sending not from activity

Answer (score 1):

You may create a listener in order to way the string. Smth like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

In the first activity

```
inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);

        //Listening to button event
        btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreenActivity.class);

                //Sending data to another Activity
                nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());

                Log.e("n", inputName.getText());

                startActivity(nextScreen);

            }
        });
```

in te next activity

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
        // Receiving the Data
        String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        Log.e("Second Screen", name);

        // Displaying Received data
        txtName.setText(name);
```